# Deserialize and cyclic dependencies in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, class-transformer

I have several model.ts files.
When I use httpClient, I get a JSON object, but it does not work correctly since I have to deserialize them: [How to recursively init class get by httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63672828/how-to-recursively-init-class-get-by-httpclient).

BUT since so, I found the project "[class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)" that help me deserialize all my models.
I have in my services:

```js
public method(cli: any): Observable<A> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('cli', JSON.stringify(cli));
    return this.http.post<A>('/my/url',
        formData, {
        withCredentials: true
    }).pipe(first(),
        map(res => {
            return plainToClass(A, res);
        })
    );
}
```

And for models something like:

```js
// A.model.ts
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { B } from './B.model';

export class A {

    // Some properties
    @Type(() => B)
    b: B[]

    // Some methods
}
```

And B

```js
// B.model.ts
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { A } from './A.model';


export class B {

    // Some properties
    @Type(() => A)
    a: A[]

    // Some methods
}
```

But, when compiling I got *"Circular dependency"* and indeed there is a circular dependency...

Looking for solution I understant that I can use a Barrel (https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/230) but it did not work.
My only constraint is that I have to keep this relation -> (or something really similar since I can not modify the backend and so data I will receive with httpClient).

Any idea on how to fix the cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used the barrel solution. It appears that in the rest of my code there were import of class A directly, I changed them to use the barrel and everything works (I still have warnings. But it works)

```js
// C.model.ts

// the problem is here
import { A } from './bla/A.model';


export class C {

}
```

```js
// C.model.ts

import { A } from './bla';

export class C {

}
```

And at `./bla` I have a `index.ts` with all the model export